# SSRS expression to get the year from the DateAdd()

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

### I am trying to get the year part from the DateAdd function. I am going wrong some where. I tried many methods but still hit with he error

Datepart("yyyy", DateAdd("M",-2,Now))
This does not work. Can you help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the year for the day two months ago:

```
=DatePart(DateInterval.Year, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, Now()))
```

**Edit after comment**

In your expression in the comment you're getting an error trying to add a string and an integer together.

So it looks like the actual requirement is to get a string like `{Month name}-{year}`.

You can do this by applying a Format expression to the date, either in the textbox directly:

```
=Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, Now()), "MMMM-yyyy")
```

Or add `MMMM-yyyy` as the Format property to a textbox with the very first expression:

[image]

Either way, for today you get:

[image]

Comment: Can we do like this =MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M",-2,Now))) + "-" + DatePart(DateInterval.Year, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, Now()))

Comment: So your actual requirement is a bit different... I've added some detail explaining your issue and a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

- MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M",-2,Now))) + " - " + DatePart(DateInterval.Year, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, Now))

This also workes when we replace '+' with '&' symbol...

- MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M",-2,Now))) & " - " & DatePart(DateInterval.Year, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, Now))